# Insert Text from Spreadsheets to Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, google-data-studio

Is there a way/workaround to display a text value (not numeric) from Google Spreadsheets in [Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com) Report?

[I found a way to display numeric values](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Data-Studio/How-to-fetch-single-cell-value-in-Data-Studio/td-p/1092109#) in Data Studio, but I couldn't replicate the same process for text values.

Answer (score -1):

It's a little bit clunky and requires some control over your dataset, but in a pinch, I've used the table layout.